# Django-mptt admin categories

Tags: python, django, mptt

In my Django project I have a model:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
name = models.CharField(default='',
                        max_length=50,
                        verbose_name='Название')
slug = models.SlugField(default='')
parent = TreeForeignKey('self',
                        related_name='children',
                        null=True,
                        blank=True,
                        verbose_name='Родительская категория'
                        )
order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=False,
                                         null=False,
                                         default=0,
                                         verbose_name='Порядок')
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True,
                                db_index=True,
                                verbose_name='Отображать на сайте')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Категория'
    verbose_name_plural = 'категории'

class MPTTMeta:
    order_insertion_by = ['order']
```

If I add the main categories first (one, two, three), and then add subcategories (four in one, five in two, six in three), I would like to see it in the admin panel like this:

```
-one
--four
-two
--five
-three
--six
```

But I have this ordering:

```
-one
-two
-three
--four
--five
--six
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to register `Category` model with `MPTTModelAdmin`
In your admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from .models import Category

admin.site.register(Category, MPTTModelAdmin)
```

Reference: https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/admin.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanx! It seems that SortableModelAdmin from suit.admin broke an order.

My admin.py was:

```
from suit.admin import SortableModelAdmin
from mptt.admin import MPTTModelAdmin
from .models import Category, Good


class CategoryAdmin(MPTTModelAdmin, SortableModelAdmin):
    mptt_level_indent = 20
    list_display = ('name', 'slug', 'is_active', 'order')
    list_editable = ('is_active',)
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("name",)}
    # Specify name of sortable property
    sortable = 'order'

admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```